# Jboss seam custom servlet "No active event context"

Tags: servlets, jboss, seam

I have jboss seam web service. I am mapping my service class in web.xml as follows

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>pluginhandler</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>service.PlugInHandler</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>pluginhandler</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>
```

I read on some blog that if you are using a custom servlet in jboss seam , then you have to add filter org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamServletFilter to generate all the required contexts which i might need to talk to seam components

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Seam Servlet Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamServletFilter</filter-class>
</filter> 
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Seam Servlet Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I have a seam component Action which I am trying to instantiate in web method , but i keep getting null pointer exception on that (when i try to invoke its method) and the root cause is "No active event context". I have attached the stack of exception as follows

```
    Servlet.service() for servlet pluginhandler threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No active event context
    at org.jboss.seam.core.Manager.instance(Manager.java:250)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.ContextualHttpServletRequest.run(ContextualHttpServletRequest.java:55)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:37)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:179)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I do not have any idea what might be wrong. Is it some specific configuration that I am missing to use custom servlets?
I would highly appreciate your help and time. i am using seam 2.0.1.GA and jboss version is 4.2.2.GA

Thanks

Comment: Do you have 'Faces Servlet' defined? You also need to go back and accept an answer (green check mark) for your previous questions if you want others to help you.

Comment: I do not use "Faces Servlet", as i am not using JSF to build UI.

Comment: So i got rid of null pointer exception for Action class, by using component.getInstance(Action.class,true) instead of Injecting (@In). But i ran into another problem now, Action class uses EntityManager , and it is throwing java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: EntityManagerFactory not found in JNDI, followed by "No active event context"

Answer (score 2):

If you are accessing Seam components in a nonstandard way you need to wrap the method call with `Lifecycle.beginCall()` and `Lifecycle.endCall()`

```
Lifecycle.beginCall() 
Component.getInstance('...').call();
Lifecycle.endCall()
```

Comment: Almost right... when in a Servlet, you can either activate ContextFilter for the URL in question (in components.xml), or wrap everything in ContextualHttpServletRequest.